# WebDAV Specification thumbnail/preview file image

Tags: apache, nginx, webdav

Now I'm using WebDAV protocol for sharing files for writing my own webdav client.

I want to implement fetching thumbnails previews from specified file located web server (nginx/Apache/other).
WebServer must generate thumbnail/preview image and return that with PROPFIND request or another way.

Is there any property from propfind or response header described in RFC and supported from webservers with nginx/Apache?

Comment: this would be really helpful for javascript based file management apps. Giving image previews when a directory has hundreds of images is a drain on network bandwidth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer is brief. There is no standard for this.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround if you control both the WebDav server and client then you can:

1. Create a [Thumbs.db](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_thumbnail_cache) file and download it. Personally I like this idea because it's clear, well known and already used in Samba
2. Add an additional tag (with own namespace) into response with thumbnail or a separate call `REPORT` as proposed here https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/w3c-dist-auth/2009AprJun/0012.html

Nextcloud/OwnCloud discussed creation of a separate Preview API but this looks like totally not related to WebDAV
https://help.nextcloud.com/t/retrieving-preview-thumbnail-wtih-webdav/95243/7

Comment: Alternatively to using Thumbs.db you can also use the [XDG specified thumbnails](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/thumbnail-spec/thumbnail-spec-latest.html#SHARED). Specification is for local files, but it's usable on WebDAV. (A proper solution would still involve having tags announcing them, but like the Thumbs.db it can serve as an immediate stopgap solution, which is also usable easily from web applications).

Comment: Interesting, just wondering that never saw such sh_thumbnails in real usage

Comment: sh_thumbnails have painfully little deployment, with [only two programs in Debian supporting it](http://codesearch.debian.net/search?q=.sh_thumbnails&literal=1). But it's part of a spec that's widely used (like, all major file managers), just they store in ~/.cache/thumbnails. However, thunar [just recently (unreleased)](https://gitlab.xfce.org/xfce/thunar/-/issues/262) grew support for shared thumbnails too.

Still, it only really works if whoever manages the shared files explicitly generates thumbnails, [like with this tool](https://github.com/jesjimher/genthumbs/blob/master/genthumbs.sh).

Comment: I think that for network shares must be chosen one format Thumbs.db or sh_thumbnails.
The Thumbs.db is definitely more known, it's often already generated and a lot apps has support of it but this is a binary format. For Linux we have a library to parse it but not sure if it's possible to quickly read and write them in Android or any other OS.
The sh_thumbnails is better specified and looks easier to use in web but less popular. 
I think that if you in control of both server and client then sh_thumbnails will be preferred because it's based on plain files and easier to use

Comment: I don't see any reason they can't coexist, if the storage overhead of duplicates is acceptable. Thumbs.db itself though seems to have been replaced by a different mechanism in "recent" versions of Windows according to [libwtcdb](https://github.com/libyal/libwtcdb/blob/main/documentation/Windows%20Explorer%20Thumbnail%20Cache%20database%20format.asciidoc). That source also indicates that the format is only partially reverse engineered, not stably documented, and primarily accessible through a platform dependent API (although it seems to be possible to read it using third party libraries).